# keep line breaks when copy and pasting from clipboard with document.execCommand('copy');

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste

how to keep line breaks when copy and pasting from clipboard with document.execCommand('copy')

Comment: Where are you trying to paste what you've copied?

Comment: @Buzinas, paste to text area